# Delphi classes registered in package A not found in package B

Tags: delphi

After some research i decided to word the question differently:
I have an application and 2 packages (BaseClasses and ClassImplementations).
BaseClasses is loaded by way of having a unit in the application uses clause:

```
uses
  BaseClasses;
```

ClassImplementations is loaded by way of LoadPackages:

```
LoadPackage("classImplementations.bpl");
```

From my application i call my parser, located in BaseClasses:

```
Parser.Parse(txt)
```

When calling code in my base classes, i have an "is" condition, checking if an implementation class IS a certain base class.

```
if classImpl is BaseClass then
```

This condition returns false.

If however i load my ClassImplementations package by way of having it in my application uses clause, that same condition returns true:

```
uses
  BaseClasses, ClassImplementations;
```

This means that classes registered in package ClassImplementations are not available in package BaseClasses.

The application uses runtime packages, containing rtl and vcl. I see that the initialization section, containing my registerclass method in classImplementations is called and that it does find the class i need in the application, but not in the BaseClasses package

What am i missing?

Comment: That would be a lot of code, i'm writing a parser. The classes do inherit from each other, otherwise it would not work if i put the ClassImplementations unit in the uses clause

Comment: I can't understand the details here. I cannot tell which units and classes are in which package and who calls what from where. This is what happens when you describe code instead of making an SSCCE. It takes time to do the latter so you think, "oh I can't be bothered to do that", and just describe it. Then you wait for ages for an answer. Or you get answers that don't apply to your actual problem because of a comms failure. Or maybe you get lucky. The SSCCE would only take 10-20 minutes to write. It might even help you solve the problem.

Comment: No need to get snappy :) I have a reasonably good idea what is going wrong, i just don't know why

Comment: No snap here. Just trying to teach problem solving. On one level you are facing a specific problem. But on a meta level, you could learn some more generic problem solving skills. Step 1: isolate and identify the problem. That's often the hard part.

Comment: I have that down :) The problem is that classes registered in package A are not available in package B

Comment: No you do not have it down. You might understand all the relationships. But you've not made them clear. For instance I have no idea where that if statement executes. If you'd made the SSCCE you would have had an answer by now. It's a simple problem. I cannot understand why people ask for help but won't take the advice on how to ask properly.

Comment: When calling code in my base classes, i have an "is" condition, checking if an implementation class IS a certain base class. Seems pretty clear to me. I appreciate you taking the time, but i feel you are getting agitated already

Comment: Have it your way then. Don't bother with an SSCCE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your dependencies. The second package "classImplementations.bpl" needs to have the first one in its `requires` clause.

Also, the main executable project needs to have the first package listed in its runtime package list in project options.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem, thank you. I didn't have the first package in the runtime package list of the application. Sometimes it's the simple things.. :) Only an upload of a full working project would have found this one :)

Comment: @Patrick You got lucky. Because the experts here can read minds. Feel free to reject my problem solving advice.

Comment: David, i'm not rejecting it. It is sound advice, but my comment is true as well, it would not have found the problem. I do thank you for your time though